# Enforcing a throw statement for a method using annotations

Tags: java, exception, annotations, aspectj

I am currently implementing a system in which I am using aspectJ to check whether a user is allowed to call a method or not. My methods look something like this:

```
@Constrained(
    mayUsers = {Constrained.Types.ADMIN, 
    Constrained.Types.SELLER, Constrained.Types.ORGANIZER}
)
public boolean save() {
    /* code */
}
```

I am able to use AspectJ to intercept the message call and do the check, but if the call is not allowed I want to throw an exception. If I just throw the `Exception` the user of the method is not informed about the `Exception` which might be thrown.

Now my question is:

Is it possible to enforce that the every method that has the `@Constrained` Annotation throws a specific `Exception`?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  This behaviour would be really nice to have.  For example you could also require a no-argument constructor for an annotated class (e. g. for `@Entity`).  But at the moment it is not possible to check this at compile time.

Comment: Ok thank you, that was a kind of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to enforce that the every method that has the
>   @Constrained Annotation throws a specific Exception?

***No*** it is not possible to do that right now. But what you can do is that at runtime you can check that all the methods that have this annotation must throw exception. If any of method does not declare throws clause, you can throw some `Illegal*Exception` to tell the developer that each method must declare throws clause.

You have two solutions:

- Compile time annotation checking using [APT (Annotation Processing Tool)](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html)
- Runtime checks (pre-conditions)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look into APT. I think that will do the job :)